# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

Code attached below. I tried to run the code, the values printed are correct but getting segmentation fault.
Can anyone explain why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[30];
    int age;
} rec[2];

void main()
{
    rec g;
    rec *pt = &g;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", &pt[i]->name);
        printf("Enter age: ");
        scanf("%d", &pt[i]->age);
    }

    printf("Name\tAge\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\t", pt[i]->name);
        printf("%d\n", pt[i]->age);
    }
```

**Output**:
[image: Output]

And also please explain the **difference** **between**

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} example[3];

example v;
```

**and**

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} example;

example v[3];
```

Comment: `pt` points to a single element `g`, so accessing `pt[1]` is illegal. You need an array.

Comment: You are defining the type `rec` as being an array of 2 anonymous structs. That is quite weird and probably not what you want. Try removing the `[2]` from the `typedef` and adding it to the variable (`rec g[2];`).

Comment: the typedef of an array is extremely odd, dont do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `void main()` is wrong. It has to be `int main(void)`
2. Here you have an example why hiding arrays behind the typedefs is a very bad habit. In your case pt[1] references the next array of two structs which outside the array bounds. You invoke undefined behaviour which can result in segfault.

You need to:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[30];
    int age;
} rec[2];

int main()
{
    rec g;
    rec *pt = &g;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", pt[0][i].name);
        printf("Enter age: ");
        scanf("%d", &(pt[0][i].age));
    }

    printf("Name\tAge\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\t", pt[0][i].name);
        printf("%d\n", pt[0][i].age);
    }
}
```

The best way is to typedef struct and define the array.

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[30];
    int age;
} rec;

int main()
{
    rec pt[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", pt[i].name);
        printf("Enter age: ");
        scanf("%d", &(pt[i].age));
    }

    printf("Name\tAge\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\t", pt[i].name);
        printf("%d\n", pt[i].age);
    }
}
```